# Shared Preferences not found

Tags: java, android, debugging, sharedpreferences

Im trying to load SharedPreferences but the shared preferences never gets found, and im trying to update it from another class but that doesn't work as well. Im using a lst adapter for a list vieew as well. Any idea's for the following code? Im getting the back up hello string for the list view.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class WorldMenu extends  ListActivity{
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
String splitter;
String[] worldList;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    context = getBaseContext();
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("worldString", 1);
    splitter =  "Create World," + prefs.getString("worldString", "hello");
    worldList = splitter.split(",");
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(WorldMenu.this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, worldList));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(position == 0){
        Intent openWorldNamer = new Intent("this works no need to check");
        startActivity(openWorldNamer);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

Edit Updater Class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WorldCreator extends Activity{
EditText worldNameEditor;
Button saver;
SharedPreferences prefs;
OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
String updater2;
Editor editor;
String updater;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_worldcreator);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    worldNameEditor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    saver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    updater2 = worldNameEditor.getText().toString() + ",";

saver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        updater = updater2;
        editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("worldString", updater);
        editor.commit();
        Intent openListWorld = new
Intent("the list activity");
        startActivity(openListWorld);

    }});

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();





    }





@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}
 }
```

Comment: Where and how do you create / set the value stored in `worldString`? Until it set it doesn't exist :-)

Answer (score 0):

Until you create preferences they don't exist, so you'll always see `"hello"`.

Here is some code I use to set a value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("LicenseAccepted", true);
editor.commit();
```

Note that this not using a named file as you are, but the concept is the same :-)

Comment: I update in another class but when I come back to the other class the same thing happens

Comment: Oh yah and now that the problem is fixed my shared preferences in the other class doesn't update it.